# What to do about obvious revenge downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes, moderation, serial-voting

After a small argument with an user this just happened to me:

[image]

I realise my first comment may have ignited everything and that some users may disagree with me, but I believe revenge downvoting isn't fair.

What can be done in this situations?

Comment: This user will likely get his account suspended. This is extremely aggressive and confrontational. Serial downvoting is not acceptable. A few serial downvotes and I think a user gets a warning from moderators but this extent.. it's flagrant and unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @CameronWilliams, I already flagged  the comment, so I'll just wait. On the other hand, is this question off-topic?

Comment: Not off-topic I think. EULER is probably trying to close it. I'm going to flag the comment as well. As academics, we should be above this petty nonsense.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Actually the closevote is mine, see the off-topic reason in the dialog. Public callouts against a user are inappropriate.

Comment: Off-topic: Thanks to the downvote in one of my questions I got the "Tumbleweed" badge :).

Comment: @Woodface Good catch on the callout issue.

Comment: @Woodface $1)$ If there is a policy, a comment for an edit could be enough. I could delete the first image in fact. $2)$ I actually googled the issue, but couldn't find any similar situation. Maybe because my misspelling of "serial".

Comment: @hjhjhj57 "serial" is the correct spelling, and cereal is a grain producing grass. Cereal strikes again!

Comment: This is about as obvious a case of serial downvoting as it gets. The site runs a script that detects and reverts such downvotes once every 24 hours. A little patience, please :-)

Comment: @J.W.Perry ;) As a native spanish speaker there's no way I can miss that one!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And what about the user?

Comment: And, yes. The moderators have access to data identifying who it was. I hope you understand why I won't give more information. In the interest of keeping this thread at a general level it may be better to remove links that allow everybody to ID the user. Also, because they may make an incorrect guess. Try not to hold a grudge. The mods will convene and discuss whether sanctions are needed, or whether we just ask a community manager to revert the votes (in the unlikely case that the automated script does not catch them).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Everything's good.